# Hyper-V Live-Migrating MongoDB Server

Tags: mongodb, windows

Does anyone know if DBs in general or in this case a Centos 7.x box running mongoDB would have corruption or any issues for that matter, if Live migrated from one host to another ?

These are hosted on Win2016 Failover Cluster/Hyper-V

Comment: Always shut down a database if you're migrating it, unless you're using native replication / backup-restore tools.

Comment: just to be clear im refering to the whole VM. in case that maters

Comment: It doesn't matter. If the database is partially in memory and not entirely committed to disk, there is a chance of corruption. Migrate it using replication technology or backup and restore.

Comment: thank you. thats what i feared.. i f one up a few years ago and im deathly afraid of these now!!!!!!